# print json data

Tags: json, jquery

This is jquery (ajax) -> php  response

```
  {"errorInfo":["23000",1062,"Duplicate entry 'blahblah' for key 'sn'"]}
```

how to print out, with jquery, only "Duplicate entry 'blahblah' for key 'sn'"

```
 success: function (html) {             
   $("#notification").fadeIn("slow")
   .text(html); //Duplicate entry 'blahblah' for key 'sn'? html->errorInfo[2]?
  }
```

thank you

UPDATE:

It's Standard PDO Error function

```
     catch(PDOException $e) {
          print json_encode($e);
      }
```

that print out like this:

```
   {"errorInfo":["23000",1062,"Duplicate entry 'SDAAASSASADASADASDAS' for key 'sn'"]}
```

UPDATE:

I change it on other side, on source, I use

```
   print json_encode($e->errorInfo[2]); instead of print json_encode($e)
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers, but still i cant make it works, Firebug: html.errorInfo is undefined

Comment: Can you explain what happens?  Do you get errors?  Can you provide sample code in jsfiddle.net?  Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gvqT3/.

Comment: @mellamokb, ty, I see your working example, but some how i am getting error message old the time "html.errorInfo is undefined"

Comment: have no idea how to put that ajax response on  jsfiddle.net :(

Comment: Can you post the whole AJAX call you make above (starting with, e.g., `$.get`), and the contents of the relevant `php` page that is called?  It may be possible for someone here to build a demonstration example by hosting the `php` page somewhere.  Also, since this is apparently just one small part of an entire `php` page, are we certain there isn't other HTML code being sent back as well, or is it just the JSON?  For example, what do you get if you add a call to `alert(html)` in the success function?

Comment: @mellamokb, it's print/alert: {"errorInfo":["23000",1062,"Duplicate entry 'SDAAASSASADASADASDAS' for key 'sn'"]}

I put it how its look like on jsFIddle, http://jsfiddle.net/nsj9c/

Comment: I have modified your code slightly.  I'm posting to `/echo/html/`, which is provided by jsfiddle to output what's posted to it.  Then I removed an extraneous `.` in the middle of the page, and commented out the code about `iddata`.  Also added the missing form `add_device`.  Now it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/nsj9c/1/.  So you need to debug what part is exactly failing.  If you use Google Chrome, you can open the console and view errors that occur during the execution of the JavaScript, and also make healthy use of `alert` statements to see where it stops working.

Comment: @mellamokb, thank you for your effort :)... yes, code works for me too on my "real" site, but what is happens when you put .text(html.errorInfo[2]) instead of .text(html)

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is `html.errorInfo[2]` or `html["errorInfo"][2]` which is equivalent. When you can (as in this case) it's customary to use the first form.

While you are at it, why not also rename the parameter from `html` to something more appropriate, like `result`?

Answer (score 2):

You're close. JavaScript uses the dot operate for objects. You're using PHP's arrow operator syntax.

```
$("#notification").fadeIn("slow").text(html.errorInfo[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (html) {             
    $("#notification").fadeIn("slow")
    .text(html.errorInfo[2]); //Duplicate entry 'blahblah' for key 'sn'? html->errorInfo[2]?
}
```